# What type of yellow-green stone is this?

Tags: rocks, crystals

It's greenish yellow with white. Got it in a mixed stone package from Amazon.

No luster, I'd say a 7 in hardness, it doesn't look homogeneous.

[image: rock][image]

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but you need to provide more information. Look at [this guide](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions) and see how many of these questions you can answer about your rock, and then edit the information into your question. A better picture is also probably a good idea.

Comment: does it fluoresce under black light? kinda looks like wernerite, that will fluoresce strongly.

Comment: What do you mean 'from Amazon'? More info? Link?

Answer (score 1):

I think your mineral specimen is smithsonite based on texture and the dark metallic specks that appear to be galena.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Scottish Green Marble or Norwegian Jade (Lizardite) ... Are there any informations about the location where it was found?

Comment: No it just came in a 1lb package from amazon. No descriptions or names included . :/